How to create scrollable background image with using UICollectionViewFlowLayout?
I want to create a scrollable background image like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8FPnpndJskjj-xRye8f1L1_QDSfqHt_/view?usp=sharing
In this case, when I scroll the collection view cells, the background image also scrolls
I'm using this code to create a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout:
StoreViewController
    class StoreViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>?
    let sections = Bundle.main.decode([Section].self, from: "section.json")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        createCollectionView()
    }

    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].identifier {
            case "carouselCell": return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            default: return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }

    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with item: Item, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue \(cellType)")
        }
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func createCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .gray
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }

    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]
            switch section.identifier {
            case "сarouselCell": return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            default: return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            }
        }
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = 20
        layout.configuration = config
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func carouselSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        var layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(0), heightDimension: .absolute(0))
        var layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
        
        switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .phone:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (a) ), heightDimension: .absolute(b))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/2, bottom: a, trailing: a/2)
            
        case .pad:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*0.25
            let h:CGFloat = a * 1.8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (h)), heightDimension: .absolute(b - (a)))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/10, bottom: 0, trailing: a/10)
            
        default:
            
            print(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        }
        
        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
        layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
            items.forEach { item in
                let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
                let minScale: CGFloat = 0.7
                let maxScale: CGFloat = 1.1
                let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
                item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            }
        }
        
        return layoutSection
    }
}

CarouselCell
    class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "carouselCell"

    let title = UILabel()
    let subtitle = UILabel()
    let bookView = UIView()
    let infoView = UIView()
    let imageView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        title.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        title.textColor = .label

        subtitle.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        subtitle.textColor = .secondaryLabel

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [infoView])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        infoView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func configure(with item: Item) {
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not happening")
    }
}

Item
public struct Item: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let tagline: String
    let name: String
    let subheading: String
    let image: String
    let iap: Bool
}

Section
public struct Section: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let identifier: String
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let item: [Item]
}

Bundle
extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        return loaded
    }
}

SelfConfiguringCell
protocol SelfConfiguringCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
    func configure(with item: Item)
}

.json
[
    {
        "index": 1,
        "identifier": "carouselCell",
        "title": "",
        "subtitle": "",
        "item": [
            {
                "index": 1,
                "tagline": "Featured",
                "name": "Strokey",
                "subheading": "You'll never stroke the same way again.",
                "image": "Heading1",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 2,
                "tagline": "See it in dark mode",
                "name": "Smartwhirl",
                "subheading": "People who love whirling just like you!",
                "image": "Heading2",
                "iap": false
            },
            {
                "index": 3,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 4,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 5,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 6,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 7,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 8,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 9,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
            {
                "index": 10,
                "tagline": "New update",
                "name": "Professorify",
                "subheading": "Introducing your portable professor.",
                "image": "Heading3",
                "iap": true
            },
        ]
    },
]

I have this mockup:

I'll try to explain. For example, I have an iPhone in a horizontal position with a screen width of 932px. And I have a background image with a width of 1864px. I also have a certain number of cells. I want to divide the width of the background image (for example 1864px.) by the number of cells (for example 10) and when the user scrolls through the cells I want the background image to move +186.4px. to the right or left depending on the direction of movement.
But how to do a scrollable background?

You want a parallax effect then?

@ReinierMelian I'll try to explain. For example, I have an iPhone in a horizontal position with a screen width of 932px. And  I have a background image with a width of 1864. I also have a certain number of cells. I want to divide the width of the background image (for example 1864) by the number of cells (for example 10) and when the user scrolls through the cells I want the background image to move 186.4 to the left or right depending on the direction of movement.

@ReinierMelian Did I explain clearly or do I need to add something?

@user1342352532 - if you provide complete code to get the layout you show in the image you posted, we can show you how to add the background image effect you're going for.

@DonMag I've added the full code to the question. I want to achieve this result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8FPnpndJskjj-xRye8f1L1_QDSfqHt_/view?usp=sharing I need to add something more info?

@user1342352532 - if you create a new project and copy/paste the code from your question, you'll see that we're still missing a lot of information to get it to run. Take a look at [mre]. I'm posting an answer that won't match your UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout but should get you on your way.

To get the "parallax" scroll effect, you want to:

embed the image in a UIView to use as the background view
get the collectionView.contentSize.width
subtract the collectionView frame width to get the "max scrollable distance" of the content
get the width of the image
subtract the collectionView frame width to get the "max scrollable distance" of the image

Then, on scroll, move the image by the percentage of the content offset.
So, consider this layout:

The content can scroll 900-points and the image can move 300-points.
So, if .contentOffset.x == 900 (scrolled as far as it can go), the "scroll percentage" will be 1.0 (100%), and we move the image 100% of its "max scrollable distance."
If .contentOffset.x == 600, it is scrolled two-thirds of its "max scrollable distance" -- so we move the image 66.6666% of its "max scrollable distance."

Edit
I've done very little with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout ... and I was surprised how difficult it was to get the "scrollable" content size and offsets.
This is what I ended up with:
let n: Int = ds.snapshot().numberOfItems

let cvw: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width
let cw: CGFloat = environment.container.contentSize.width

let groupWidth: CGFloat = layoutGroupSize.widthDimension.dimension

// because layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior  is set to .groupPagingCentered
//  the actual scrollable width is center of item 0 to center of last item
let scrollableWidth: CGFloat = groupWidth * CGFloat(n - 1)

// get the group midX
let groupMidX = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: environment.container.contentSize).midX

// calculate x-offset for first centered group
let baseOffsetX: CGFloat = (groupMidX - (groupWidth * 0.5)) - ((cvw - cw) * 0.5)

// percent we are currently scrolled, of total scrollable width
let pctScrolled: CGFloat = (offset.x + baseOffsetX) / scrollableWidth

Using this image (named "scrollingBackground" in assets) as an example - it is 1200 x 393 so it fits based on an iPhone 15 Pro:

When running, the app looks like this:



Not entirely obvious from these pics, but the background scrolls at the percentage of the collection view scrolling.

This is the "background view" class:
class BkgImageView: UIView {
    
    public let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    // controls the x-offset of the image view, inside self
    public var xPercent: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            let myWidth: CGFloat = bounds.width
            let imgWidth: CGFloat = imgView.bounds.width
            let moveWidth: CGFloat = imgWidth - myWidth
            // keep it between 0.0 and 1.0 (0% and 100%)
            let pct = min(1.0, max(0.0, xPercent))
            leadingConstraint.constant = -(moveWidth * pct)
        }
    }
    
    private var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guard let theImage = UIImage(named: "scrollingBackground")
        else { fatalError("Could not load background image!") }
        
        imgView.image = theImage
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        leadingConstraint = imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: theImage.size.width),
            leadingConstraint,
        ])
    }
}


So, here is your code (minus the .json) - modified to use a "parallax" scrolling background:
///**StoreViewController**

class StoreViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>?
    let sections = Bundle.main.decode([Section].self, from: "section.json")
    
    let bkgView = BkgImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        createCollectionView()
        
        collectionView.backgroundView = bkgView
        bkgView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
    
    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, item in
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].identifier {
            case "carouselCell": return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            default: return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with item: Item, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue \(cellType)")
        }
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func createCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .gray
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }
    
    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]
            switch section.identifier {
            case "сarouselCell": return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            default: return self.carouselSection(using: section)
            }
        }
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        // .interSectionSpacing has no effect?
        //  changing it doesn't seem to change the layout...
        config.interSectionSpacing = 120
        layout.configuration = config
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func carouselSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        // using .absolute(0) throws a warning, and may (will) cause a fatal error in the future
        //  since we're updating it immediately, set it to .absolute(1)
        //var layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(0), heightDimension: .absolute(0))
        var layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(1), heightDimension: .absolute(1))
        var layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
        
        switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .phone:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (a) ), heightDimension: .absolute(b))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/2, bottom: a, trailing: a/2)
            
        case .pad:
            
            let a:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*0.25
            let h:CGFloat = a * 1.8
            let b:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            
            layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(b - (h)), heightDimension: .absolute(b - (a)))
            layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
            layoutGroup.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: a, leading: a/10, bottom: 0, trailing: a/10)
            
        default:
            
            print(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        }
        
        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
        layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] items, offset, environment in
            items.forEach { item in
                let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
                let minScale: CGFloat = 0.7
                let maxScale: CGFloat = 1.1
                let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
                item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            }
            
            guard let self = self,
                  let ds = self.dataSource
            else { return }
            
            // no apparent built-in property of "scrollable content size"
            //  so let's jump through some hoops to calculate it
            // we could probably make these class properties, and only update them
            //  on frame change, but that's for another time...
            
            let n: Int = ds.snapshot().numberOfItems

            let cvw: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width
            let cw: CGFloat = environment.container.contentSize.width

            let groupWidth: CGFloat = layoutGroupSize.widthDimension.dimension
            
            // because layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior  is set to .groupPagingCentered
            //  the actual scrollable width is center of item 0 to center of last item
            let scrollableWidth: CGFloat = groupWidth * CGFloat(n - 1)

            // get the group midX
            let groupMidX = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: environment.container.contentSize).midX
            
            // calculate x-offset for first centered group
            let baseOffsetX: CGFloat = (groupMidX - (groupWidth * 0.5)) - ((cvw - cw) * 0.5)
            
            // percent we are currently scrolled, of total scrollable width
            let pctScrolled: CGFloat = (offset.x + baseOffsetX) / scrollableWidth

            // tell the background view to update its image view x-offset
            self.bkgView.xPercent = pctScrolled
        }
        
        return layoutSection
    }
}

///**CarouselCell**

class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "carouselCell"
    
    let title = UILabel()
    let subtitle = UILabel()
    let bookView = UIView()
    let infoView = UIView()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        title.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        title.textColor = .label
        
        subtitle.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        subtitle.textColor = .secondaryLabel
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [infoView])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        infoView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        
        title.textColor = .white
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        infoView.addSubview(title)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            
            title.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.centerXAnchor),
            title.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(with item: Item) {
        title.text = "\(item.index) \(item.name)"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not happening")
    }
}

///**Item**

public struct Item: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let tagline: String
    let name: String
    let subheading: String
    let image: String
    let iap: Bool
}

///**Section**

public struct Section: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let identifier: String
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let item: [Item]
}

///**Bundle**

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        
        return loaded
    }
}

///**SelfConfiguringCell**

protocol SelfConfiguringCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
    func configure(with item: Item)
}


II've added the full source code to the question. I launched and tested it. I also read the your answer to the question. But in which method should I do this calculation?I can get collectionView.frame.width in createCollectionView but where do I get collectionView.contentSize.width?

If I use collectionView.contentSize.width I get wrong size. I need to get NSCollectionLayoutSection size instead collectionView.contentSize.width?
